# missing class SamlSecurityTokenHandler in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, saml

I need to create a securitytoken out of a received answer (saml assertion). From what I read here and on the internet, it seems I need the SamlSecurityTokenHandler class. This class is supported in .net framework 4.5. I'm running 4.5.5. but I this class is not in the namespace System.IdentityModel.Tokens. 
[See msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenhandlercollection(v=vs.110).aspx)
What can be wrong here?

Comment: "I'm running 4.5.5" - um, no, you're not. Since 4.5 there's been 4.5.1, 4.5.2 and 4.6. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx). So maybe work out what versions of things you are working with as a first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `System.IdentityModel` assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already done that, I can find and use several classes (SamlAssertion, SamlSecurityToken) , but not 'SamlSecurityTokenHandler'.

Comment: @StevenCool I tried it in VS2012 with .NET 4.5 and 4.5.1. `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityTokenHandler` is in assembly `System.IdentityModel.dll, v4.0.0.0`. Had a look in the object browser?

Comment: Yes, I have taken a look in the object browser: in the list of classes I have 'SamlNameIdentifierClaimResource', then 'SamlSecurityToken' and then 'SamlSerializer'. But no SamlSecurityTokenHandler. I'm using VS2010 but I guess that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @StevenCool What happens if you try targetting 4.5.1 or 4.5.2?

Comment: There's your problem then - that class didn't exist until 4.5.

Comment: Which isn't supported in VS2010. I'm afraid it doesn't matter whether you have 4.5 installed on your system or not.